# How can i cancel default binds of headings adding like Alt + Shift + 1, i need to restrict all heading tags for TinyMCE editor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tinymce, tinymce-6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rGeV.png)

I canceled the heading adding from the panel but key combination remained, how can i restrict that too?

I try to cancel key up adding headings combination, i expected a code for tinyMCE editor which allows me to cancel that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.